# Rails Ajax Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working on an dynamic edit of an article using rails. On each articles can be added paragraphs. I wanted to use Ajax with Jquery following the 136-jquery-ajax-revised tutorial from railscast. I created the template for the form and the new.js.erb response but I keep geting same error:

ParagraphsController#new is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []

This is the link that request the new form from view/article/show

```
<%= link_to 'New Paragraph', new_article_paragraph_path(@article), remote: true, class: 'uk-button uk-button-primary' %>
```

view/paragraph/_form

```
<div class="article-form-container">
  <%= form_with scope: :paragraph, url: article_paragraphs, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'uk-input', placeholder: 'Title of paragraph (optional, can be a subtitle of the article)' %>
    <%= f.text_area :text, class: 'uk-textarea', placeholder: 'Content of paragraph' %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :position, :value => 3 %>
    <div class="submit-button">
    <%= f.submit class: 'uk-button uk-button-primary' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

routes

```
resources :articles, only: %i[show update destroy create]

resources :articles do
  resources :paragraphs, only: %i[new create update destroy]
end
```

view/paragraphs/new.js.erb

```
$('div#article-control-panel').hide("fast", function () {
    $('div#article-control-panel').after('<%= j render 'form' %>')
})
```

controllers/paragraphs_controller

```
class ParagraphsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @paragraph = Paragraph.new
  end

  def create
    @paragraph = Paragraph.new(paragraph_params)
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])

    if @article.user == current_user
      @paragraph.article = @article
      @paragraph.save
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @article }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def paragraph_params
    params.require(:paragraph).permit(:title, :text, :position)
  end
end
```

Can't figure out what the problem is. The error happens in the article page, after I press the link button.

**Edit**
Strange thing is that if i try to change the url of orm in something like article_path it will work...

Comment: Could you post your controller’s code?

Comment: sure, sry I forget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is missing a `respond_to`. Your new function should look like this:

```
def new
  @paragraph = Paragraph.new
  respond_to { |format| format.js }
end
```

This `respond_to` allows rails to call the relevant `.js.erb` file, in this instance your `new.js.erb` file.

Just keep in mind that when you want to perform an ajax call, you require these few elements:

- A `respond_to { |format| format.js }` in your controller action
- Your `js.erb` file needs to be the same name as your controller action (`foo.js.erb`)
- A partial to render through your `js.erb` file, typically named the same as your js file. (`_foo.js.erb`)
- If it is a link, you need `remote: true`. If it is a form and you're using rails 5, you could use `form_with` or simply include `remote: true` too.

Comment: ActionController::UnknownFormat in ParagraphsController#new at line
4 respond_to do |format|. Didn't seems like he's going for the js template, can't understand why since I write, remote: true

Comment: This is likely a routing error. Could you run `rails routes | grep paragraph` to confirm if the route you’re passing into your link is right?

Comment: now that I checked, the sintax was wrong. I fixed it... thanks for help and advices

Comment: @Jarlio glad to help :)